# d-mesh generation using constrained delaunay triangulation

Tags: cgal

are there examples of doing 3d-mesh generation using constrained delaunay triangulation?

I see there is constrained triangulation in 2d but not in their 3d mesh generation.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no implementation of a constrained Delaunay triangulation in 3D, in CGAL.

There is one in [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/index.jsp?id=TetGen), but I am not sure there is an API for it.